# Spring application context is not destroyed even after calling destroy method

Tags: spring

An application context is not getting destroyed though we are calling destroy method.

```
public void destroyContext() {
    if (applicationCtxt != null) {
      logger.info("Started Destroying ApplicationContext ");
      ((AbstractApplicationContext)applicationCtxt).close();
      applicationCtxt = null;
      serviceLocator = null;
      logger.info("Destroyed ApplicationContext ");
    }
 }
```

In the loggers, the log statement is "Destroyed ApplicationContext" is coming, but when we see in the memory dumps(IBM WAS7.0.0.23), still the application and All the DAO's are exists.

Comment: and which `applicationContext` is that and why are you closing it yourself?

Comment: You aren't destroying anything you are only closing the context. If there are still references to the context it will not be GC'ed. Also if you have both a `DispatcherServlet` and `ContextLoaderListener` you have multiple contexts so destroying one whilst there are more isn't helpful either.

Comment: From SPRING API, if we call the close(), it  Close this application context, destroying all beans in its bean factory". http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html. In our application, we are not GUI app, so we are not using web.xml to configure DispatcherServlet or ContextLoaderListener